# Java Function With Optional Listed Parameters

Tags: java, outputstream

I'm rewriting a logging class in a Java application. One of the primary logging functions that we have uses an object to determine where the output is. What I want to do is get rid of that object, and have the output streams listed directly in the parameters as optional parameters like so:

```
Logger.log("Log String Here", stdout, trace, debug, device1);
```

Where stdout, trace, and debug are optional parameters, and may not exist, but could also exist in any order. For example, one could also write the following:

```
Logger.log("Log String Here", debug, trace, deviceTrace);
```

Can this be done in Java 8 using the Optional class or would I have to combine the output streams into a string or array?

Comment: You can overload the variations that you know that exist or perhaps use variable arguments in a single method that then will have to do a lot of type checks to find which is the variation in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 `Optional` has no relation to what you are seeking. An `Optional` is a wrapper of an instance of some class, which can save you some null checks. If you use `Optional` arguments in your method, you still have to pass all those arguments in each call to your `log` method (even if some of them are empty).

If all your optional parameters have a common base class or interface, you can use a varargs argument.

For example :

```
public static void log (String message, OutputStream... output) {

}
```

However, you can't pass them in any order. For example, you'll have to decide what's the role of `output[0]`, and `output[1]` can only be passed if `output[0]` is also passed.

The alternative is to have multiple overloaded methods with different combinations of arguments.